# Make structure loose coupling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am stuck in deciding a good structure for Node.js + MongoDB. I read some article about Layers structure for project then I make 3 layer: Controller, Service and DAL. But when I implement it, I think there are some dependencies in my structure. Could someone help me to correct it?

```
export class Controller {
  userService: Service;
  constructor(userService: Service) {
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  async searchByKeyword(keyword) {
    return await this.userService.searchByKeyword(keyword);
  }
}

export class Service {
   articlesDAL: DAL;
   constructor(articlesDAL: DAL) {
      this.articlesDAL = articlesDAL;
   }

   async searchByKeyword(keyword: string) {
      return await this.articlesDAL.searchByKeyword(keyword);
   }
}

export class DAL {
   constructor() {}

   async searchByKeyword(keyword: string) {
      return await ArticleModel.searchFullText(keyword);
   }
}
```

In my main function

```
route.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   let userDal = new DAL();
   let userService = new Service(userDal);
   let userController = new Controller(userService);
   const {
      query: { keyword },
   } = req;

   const result = await userController.searchByKeyword(keyword);

   res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: The controller layer is currently a bit pointless - the function you pass to the router _is_ the controller.

Comment: yes agree @jonrsharpe ! I think I will use the service inside the main function. But Also I am worry about create service inside the route ? Is it good or is there any good replace for that?